# In the transition from set theory to order theory, what is the appropriate generalization of "group"?

Tags: group-theory, terminology, order-theory

Given a set $X$, the collection of all bijective endofunctions on $X$ forms a group, called the symmetric group on $X.$ Furthermore, Cayley's theorems says that every group embeds into a subgroup of the symmetric group on its underlying set.

**Question.** If we want to replace "set" with "poset," and "bijective endofunction" with "endomorphism that occurs as the lower adjoint of some Galois connection," what is the correct concept to replace "group" with?

Comment: I don't know so much about combinatorics, but I imagine that you just want "groups which happen to occur as automorphism groups of some poset," which I imagine turns out to be the same as "groups." (The point is, if you are in some category, and OBJECT is replacing set, then AUT(OBJECT) should replace group. But I don't understand your category well enough to tell you what sorts of groups appear as AUT(OBJECT).)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is considered in the book [*Lattices and Ordered Algebraic Structures*](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b139095/page/1) by Blyth. Given a poset $X$, he writes $\operatorname{Res}(X)$ for the semigroup of 'residuated' functions (i.e., lower adjoints) $X\to X$, and presents the following result of [Johnson](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2-4/2/277.full.pdf).

> **Theorem 1.12**: If $X$ is a bounded poset then $\operatorname{Res}(X)$ is a generalised Baer semigroup.

Generalised Baer semigroups (or 'pre-Baer' semigroups in Johnson's terminology) are characterised by some annihilator conditions. Specifically, a semigroup $S$ having an identity element $1\in S$ and a zero element $0\in S$ is a *generalised Baer semigroup* if for each $a\in S$ there exist $a_r,a_l\in S$ satisfying $LR(a)=L(a_r)$ and $RL(a)=R(a_l)$, where
$$\begin{align}R(b)&=\{c\in S:bc=0\}\quad\text{and}\\
L(b)&=\{c\in S:cb=0\}\end{align}$$
are the *right* and *left annihilators* of $b\in S$.